# Cannot invoke initializer of type 'PFObject'

Tags: parse-platform, swift2, ios9

In a view controller with a table view in my app I have a query getting data for all of the events the user is attending. This works just fine but I also want to get all of the events the user created as well.

The first "if let" statement works fine but the second throws the error

```
Cannot invoke initializer of type 'PFObject' with an argument list of type (withoutDataWithClassName...)
```

Any help? Thanks!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let events = PFUser.currentUser()?["eventsToAttend"] as? [String] {
    self.eventsToAttend = [Event]()
    for eventId in events {
        if let event = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Event", objectId: eventId) as? Event {

            self.eventsToAttend?.append(event)
        }
    }
    }

    if let eventsCreated = PFUser.currentUser()?["Events"] as? [String] {

        self.eventsCreated = [Event]()

        for eventCreated in eventsCreated {

            if let eventC = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Event", objectId: eventsCreated) as? Event {

                self.eventsCreated?.append(eventC)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have both an eventsCreated and a self.eventsCreated.  Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, I've done that before in other classes/projects and had no problem. I tried changing it just in case and the error persists. Very strange.